# Is it haram to have a poster of planets or rockets

Tags: practical-islam

I am trying to get a new poster about rockets but someone told me that posters are haram?

Answer (score 0):

It's fine you can get them, your friend probably thinks it's haram because of worshipping the poster, which I'm assuming you won't worship a rocket poster. If you have innocent intentions then it's fine getting a poster.